# Best practice implementation of functions-family in cpp

Tags: c++, template-specialization, static-assert

## Preliminary

A functions-family is a countable list of functions `y=f_i(x)`, for a counter i=0,...,n-1 for some integer n.

## Minimum example

I have a derived struct in c++ that shall define such a functions-family for `n=3`:

```cpp
template<typename Tfloat, size_t n> Base{
  template<size_t i> bool f(Tfloat* x){ static_assert(i<n); return false; }
};

template<typename Tfloat>
struct Derived: Base<Tfloat,3>{
  template<> bool f<0>(Tfloat* x){ x[3]-=x[2]; return true; }
  template<> bool f<1>(Tfloat* x){ x[1]*=x[3]; return true; }
  template<> bool f<2>(Tfloat* x){ if(x[5]==0) return false; x[2]/=x[5]; return true; }
};
```

## Question

How can I achieve the following?:

1. force by virtue of inheritance from Base<Tfloat,3> at compile-time that all three functions of the family are defined.
2. I need to be able to statically loop through f with, e.g. an `std::sequence<n>`. Until now, I have given a different name `f0, f1,...` to each function. But then one must manually write an `if constexpr(i=0){ return f0(x); }` wrapper to traverse through all names in the definition of `template<size_t i> f(Tfloat* x)`. Acutally, this is how I am doing it as of now.
3. Be able to write the definitions within the body of Derived.

## Issues

I know that there are a dozen of issues:

- one cannot specialize a template function within the scope of Derived.
- one cannot even specialize a template function of an un-specialized Derived at all.
- and while a call of `f<i>` for `i>=n` can be statically prohibited, I see no way to enforce definedness for all `i=0,...,n-1` .

Thus I am very curious for your ideas.

## Remarks

- Typically, the functions for different `i` have very little to do with one another; e.g., physical models for the `i`-th stage of a rocket. I prefer the use of template for `size_t i`.
- Derived typically holds run-time dependent parameters and data computed/initialized from these parameters. Hence, the use of a namespace instead of struct for Derived appears unsuitable to me.

## Proposal: Function Array

Taken from @HolyBlackCat's comment:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<array>

template<typename Tfloat, size_t n>
class Base{
protected:
    std::array<std::function<bool(Tfloat*)>,n> f_;
public:
    // probably here in conjunction with an invalid default initialize for each element of f_, CRTP could be used to assert after construction of derived that each f_[i] is defined?
    template<size_t i>
    bool f(Tfloat* x){ return f_[i](x); } // accessor prevents external overwrite into f_.
};

template<typename Tfloat>
class Derived: public Base<Tfloat,3>{
public:
    //
    Derived(){
        Base<Tfloat,3>::f_[0] = [this](Tfloat* x){
            x[0] *= x[1];
            return true;
        };
    }
    //
};

template<typename Tfloat>
struct NaiveDerived{
    //
    bool f0(Tfloat* x){
        x[0] *= x[1];
        return true;
    }
    //
};

int main(){
    Derived<float> d;
    float x[10];
    d.f[0](x);
}
```

This code works and achieves the requirements 2 and 3.

I do not like the use of a function array much because eventually we want to marry two things:

- a function body of the i-th function `{ x[0]*=x[1]; return true; }`
- a template function name of the i-th function `f<i>(x)`

Introducing `f_` into the mix only accomplishes to avoid giving names to each function body before we assign said body to its respective `f<i>`. More readable would be a solution that states the `i`-th function body directly with `f<i>`.

Comment: You can just use an array (or `std::vector`) of function pointers (or `std::function`s).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Do you propose ``std::array<std::function<bool>(Tfloat*),n> a`` and then setting ``a[0]= f0; a[1]=f1; ...`` ? In that case that seems to be what I am doing, which has the boilerplate that each ``a[i]`` has to be assigned to a function definition that still has to exist somewhere. The question is actually on how I could organizedly pose the definitions, augmented with compile-time assertions.

Comment: In your case I'd rather use function pointers, since they seem to have no state, but yes. *"function definition that still has to exist somewhere"* You can use lambdas, then you don't need anything other than the array itself.

Comment: Check [CRTP][1] C++  pattern.


  [1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp

Comment: What's the role of `Base`? How is the calling code using it? Is there some form of polymorphism going on?

Comment: @Red.Wave. While I am familiar to the pattern, I have never found use in it. Can you clarify how it helps here? Is it helpful for the requirement on definedness? That could be very interesting if I could just see how it helps.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. Base is a base class for function-families of n members. Ideally, as per requirement 1, any derived of Base<Tfloat,n> would have to provide member function definiotions for f<0>,...,f<n-1> with signature bool(Tfloat*) for the case of the minimum example.

Comment: Any member function of the base is instantiated at call site; if it calls a member of derived type at this point it must have been defined, or compilation fails. You cannot check for existance of the function, but you can force it via calling a base member.

Comment: CRTP is compile-time polymorphism.  Base class statically casts itself to the derived type and calls the derived-specific implementation. No virtual functions needed.

Comment: If you put `static_assert`s in a base function (dtor) then upon instantiating the class you get diagnostics on missing functions. For your code, some variadic template voodoo is needed too.

Comment: Take a look at `std::integer_sequence` library as well **fold expression** syntax too. You're gonna like it.

Comment: What does the call site look like? Does it mention `Base` in any way, or is it purely an internal implementation detail? On the surface, it doesn't appear to add any value; you seem to want it solely for purposes of ideological purity - to be able to point to it and say "this is *functions-family*". But does it really matter to the calling code that the class it works with meets your definition of *functions-family*?

Comment: @Red.Wave. Sorry, I know the integer_sequence. I use it to "for-loop" over f<i>. Can you elaborate on how with the CRTP it achieves 1 ? I coded out the function array with the definition of base. If you want to copy-paste that into an answer and add the CRTP trick to it, I would gain a lot of understanding. While I understand I could call a function of derived from the constructor of Base when constructing Derived, I do not see how I can ensure that each field of f_ has been written into. I assume destructor is critical so a derived function is called after the derived deletor?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. I want for instance a solver to require that a problem statement a (an instance of a class object) is an inheritant of a functions-family of length n=5 (for instance). That is how the base class would come in handy. And then the solver knows "Okay, I can actually evaluate a.f<0>(67.8);" .

Comment: So it doesn't sound like you necessarily want that the class be derived from `Base`. All that matters is that `Derived().f<i>(x)` is well-formed. It's possible to write a trait that checks for that directly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. I agree further with you that it seems to be "idiologicism" if in fact the "best way" of implementing it is by assigning yet other function bodies to an array of functions. I personal feel like the array of functions is a vehicle to get from a function body with an identifier to a template function specialization. My minimum example writes down this shortcut, but the working proposal needs the function array as "bridge". And if you say this bridge is an inherent necessity, then we could scrap base altogether, I agree.

Comment: I'm saying that you can drop `Base`, move the primary `f` template into `Derived`, and specialize it to your heart's content. And if you want your solver to verify that `a.f<0>(67.8)` is a well-formed expression, there are ways to do that that don't rely on any particular implementation detail. That's where traits (or concepts, if you can use a sufficiently modern C++ standard) come in.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. I think this is not possible, because: 1) the specialization f<0> cannot be defined in the body of Derived. 2) Base and Derived is template, thus each specialization would have to be written for each possible realization of Tfloat in Base/Derived. Is my information false or do I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you might change signature, i.e calling `d.f(IC<0>{}, x);` and not `d.f<0>(x);`

Following might help, using `virtual` to ensure functions existence:

```
// shorten code
template <std::size_t N>
using IC = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

// helper node I
template <typename T, size_t I> struct BaseNode
{
    virtual ~BaseNode() = default;
    virtual bool f(IC<I>, T* x) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename Seq> struct BaseImpl;

template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct BaseImpl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : BaseNode<T, Is>...
{
    using BaseNode<T, Is>::f...;
};

// Use expecting name
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using Base = BaseImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

//  The derived class
template<typename Tfloat>
struct Derived : Base<Tfloat,3>{
  bool f(IC<0>, Tfloat* x) override { x[3]-=x[2]; return true; }
  bool f(IC<1>, Tfloat* x) override { x[1]*=x[3]; return true; }
  bool f(IC<2>, Tfloat* x) override { if(x[5]==0) return false; x[2]/=x[5]; return true; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vYzT478Tb)

Comment: That is the perfect answer to my problem. Many thanks! And the syntax ``d.f<0>(x)`` can still be used by renaming f in your code and defining ``bool f<i>(T* x){ return f_(IC<i>{},x);}`` in BaseImpl.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
template <std::size_t n> 
using index_constant = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, n>;
template<typename arg, std::size_t m>
struct base{
    template<std::size_t n>
    requires (n < m)
    bool f(this auto& self, index_constant<n> i, arg val){ return self.f_impl(i, std::forward<arg>(val));
    /*~base(this auto& self){
         [&]<std::size_t...i>(std::index_sequence<i...>)
         {static_assert((
              std::is_same_v<
                   bool,
                   decltype(self.f_impl(index_constant<i>{}, std::declval<arg>()))
              >&&...
         ));} (std::make_index_sequence<m>{});
    };*/
};

struct derived: base<float, 3>{
     template<std::size_t n>
     bool f_impl(index_constant<n>, float){ return true; };
};

/*...*/
derived d;
bool flag=[&d]<std::size_t ...i>(std::index_sequence<i...>)
    {return (d.f(index_constant<i>,1.0f) && ...);}
    (std::make_index_sequence<3>{});
```

In the `base` class, I have used the C++ deduced `this` feature to simplify CRTP, and avoid the verbose usage of derived. You can work your way out of compile time traversal of indices through fold expressions and generic lambdas as shown in the sample above.

**Edit:**

Constructor and destructor are not the best place to detect the actual type. It was a folly on my side.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating your proposal. I learned a lot from it. I think though that Jarod42's solution is better because it allows users to implement functions with a simpler syntax, and the solution is easier to comprehend for a developer.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I guess there's a problem in the snippet. I should comment out the problematic part.